# How to pass `false` value to Helm `default`?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

A pattern I've often seen in Helm charts ([e.g.](https://github.com/k8s-at-home/charts/blob/77d4398e0a1c7393d180d1c987bf718245ff91e2/charts/incubator/dendrite/templates/dendrite-config.yaml#L87)) is to set a boolean value to [default](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function) to `true` unless some overriding value is provided:

```
feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource: {{ default true .Values.foo_feature_enabled }}
```

That is - "*if `foo_feature_enabled` is set to any value in the inputs to Helm (via `--set`, `values.yaml`, etc.), set `feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource` to that value - else (if it is unset), set `feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource` to `true`*"

However, I'm not able to override that value as I would expect - both setting a `false` value in `values.yaml`, and/or passing `--set foo_feature_enabled=false` as an argument, still result in the template holding a value of `true`.

I suspect that this is because `false` is a "[*falsy*](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362)" value, and so `default` parses it as "needing replacement".

Passing a string value (`"false"` in `values.yaml`, or `--set-string foo_feature_enabled=false`) does appear (from `helm template [...]` output) to set `feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource` to `"false"` - but it's not clear whether that will be correctly interpreted by the actual application which results from the Kubernetes (that is - it might interpret a non-empty string as "truthy", setting us right back to the original default behaviour). Even if this *works*, it feels hacky in a way that suggests that I'm missing the "proper" solution.

(Presumably, the *actual* fix would be Helm charts to never `default` to `true` - but that doesn't help me when working with charts that I don't control!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of "truthiness" in combination with `default` is correct here: [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) considers `0`, `false`, `nil`, and empty strings all as "unset" and replaces them with the default value.  So if you expect `.Values.something` to have a Boolean value, `.Values.something | default true` will always be `true`.

The least-code solution to this is to specify a value in your chart's `values.yaml` file:

```yaml
# values.yaml

# foo_feature_enabled enables the foo feature.
foo_feature_enabled: true
```

```yaml
# templates/configmap.yaml
feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource: {{ .Values.foo_feature_enabled }}
```

Now a `helm install --set foo_feature_enabled=false` option will override the chart's `values.yaml` file.  But if you don't have that option, there's a default value in `values.yaml` to use.

If that's not an option, then you need to explicitly check whether the value is set using [`hasKey`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#haskey) in an `if` block.  All of the other shorthands have the same "truthiness" check.

```yaml
# templates/configmap.yaml
feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource:
{{- if hasKey .Values "foo_feature_enabled" }} {{ .Values.foo_feature_enabled }}
{{- else }} true
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Relatedly: since 0 is falsey, `replicas: {{ .Values.replicas | default 1 }}` doesn't allow an operator to disable a Deployment by specifying zero replicas at deploy time.

Answer (score 7):

A clean (albeit a little unclear) solution using [ne](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ne) (not-equal)

```yaml
feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource: {{ ne .Values.foo_feature_enabled false }}
```

| `.Values.foo_feature_enabled` | true | false | null or empty | *not specified* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource` | true | false | true | true |

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `ternary` function:

```yaml
feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource: {{ hasKey .Values "foo_feature_enabled" | ternary .Values.foo_feature_enabled true }}
```

It is longer than using `ne` but it is clear at first sight.

Answer (score -1):

Helm evaluates from left to right, hence, in the way it is used it will always be set to true. The Value that is being passed will not matter at all. Change the above to:

```
feature_enabled_in_k8s_resource: {{ .Values.foo_feature_enabled | default true }}
```

This will evaluate the supplied Value first, and if not supplied, will use default true value.

Please refer [using pipelines in helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function).

Comment: "Change the above to:" - I'd love to, but I don't control that chart :) is there a way to pass values into this incorrect setup such that it will act as intended?

Comment: Passing false to a default function (https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) evaluates as empty, which in turn forces the value that the template has specified. K8s-at-home charts is a public archive now, it will not be updated. Hopefully the dendrite template will show up soon in some other active repository. For now, if I were you, I will clone it locally, modify the lines as suggested and use helm from local folder as mentioned in here (https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/). Let me know if you need any help.